# How to use slice at the end of a function

Tags: javascript, slice

simple question. I am learning Javascript and I don't understand why slice() won't do anything to my response let.

accum() is a function that takes a string.

```js
 
     function accum(s) {
  let response = '';
   for (i=0; i < s.length; i++) {
    response += (s.charAt(i).toUpperCase()) + (s.charAt(i).toLowerCase()).repeat(i)  + '-'
   }
 
  return response.slice(0, response.length-1)
  }

console.log(accum("abCdEf"))
```

The function still returns `response`as if I didn't slice it.

Comment: What are you expecting as result from that function ? can you be more clear ? I've edited your question to console.log the result of calling the function and seems to be doing what is supposed to do. Please can you be more specific about the output

Comment: I've updated the console.log so you can have a better idea of what the purpose of the function was. The slice() was to get rid of the last '-' at the end of the response. Maybe this could be refactored in a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`slice()` does not mutate the existing string (or array) - rather, it returns a *new string* (or array), containing the portion of the old string or array that was sliced.

If you want to return the sliced portion, then do so with `return response.slice(1)`. This will return the `response` string, without its first character.

Comment: If you return the sliced portion, it does not return the same result. For example, calling `accum` with `abc` results in `A-Bb-Ccc-` without the `.slice`, and `-Bb-Ccc-` with the `.slice`.